# NodeJS MySQL check multiple

Tags: mysql, node.js

So, this code here is causing some issues (I won't go into checking multiple and flashing messages at the same time right now cause I'm already lost on how to check them individually). So when I remove the kingdom and email from the list, it works fine if I just use "rows.length". I would like to check for all three fields, and then after those check then go into the registration process.

UPDATED

```
router.post('/register', function(req, res, next){

  const username = req.body.username;
  const kingname = req.body.kingname;
  const email = req.body.email;
  const password = req.body.password;
  const password2 = req.body.password2;


  req.checkBody('username', 'Username is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('kingname', 'Kingdom Name is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('email', 'E-Mail is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password', 'Password is Required').notEmpty();
  req.checkBody('password2', 'Passwords do not match').equals(password);

  let errors = req.validationErrors();

    db.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE username = ? OR kingname = ? OR email = ?', [username, kingname, email], function(err, rows){
if(err) {
  console.log(err);
  res.redirect('/');
  return;
} else {
  var rowLength = rows.length;
  for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
    if(i.username == req.body.username) {
      console.log('Username is Taken');
      req.flash('success', 'Username is taken');
      res.redirect('/');
    } else if (i.email == req.body.kingname) {
      console.log('Kingdome Name Taken');
      req.flash('success', 'Kingdom Name Taken');
      res.redirect('/');
    } else if (i.email == req.body.email) {
      console.log('Email already registered');
      req.flash('success', 'Email already registered');
      res.redirect('/');
    }
  }
}
  });
```

Updated

ERROR:

> ```
>   for (var = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
>            ^
> ```
>
> SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Okay so I ended up including the rest of my code, because I think it may be some of the opther things I have done, that are causing issues, as well.

Comment: Easiest way is to put a `UNIQUE` index constraint on these columns so any duplicates result in an error on insert.

Comment: I've already done that. But, I'd rather check for it rather then let it try to insert and fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, I think you really want to check all things that are taken and provide one response, rather than a redirect on every field.  Your query can also be optimized a bit by only selecting the actual fields you care about.

Also, you need to be checking the individual row, not the rows array, when doing your field checks.

Finally, you should just be using 'if' statements rather than 'else if' since you can have both a duplicate username and a duplicate email, potentially.

For example, something like this:

```
db.query('SELECT username, kingname, email FROM users WHERE username = ? OR kingname = ? OR email = ?', [username, kingname, email], function(err, rows){
    if(err) {
      console.error(err);
      return res.redirect('/');
    } else {
      var rowLength = rows.length;
      var duplicateFields = [];
      for (var i = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
        var row = rows[i];
        if(row.username == username) {
          duplicateFields.push('username');
        }

        if (row.kingname == kingname) {
          duplicateFields.push('kingname');
        }

        if (row.email == email) {
          duplicateFields.push('username');
        }
      }
      if (duplicateFields.length) {
         console.error('Duplicate fields: ', duplicateFields.join(','));
         req.flash('error', duplicateFields.join(',') + ' are already taken'); // obviously, you can adjust this however you want
         return res.redirect('/')
      } else {
         res.render('/'); // or whatever
      }
    }
  });
```

Comment: Awesome this works! However... it doesn't show each one if more than one is wrong. I mean it's not THAT important o have that done, but it would be a little nice.

Comment: It shows a list in one flash message. That's the point of the duplicate fields array

Comment: I understand that, but it is not showing it all. It just shows the first one (in my case, the username). I made sure I was using duplicates in all fields to test it. It should look like: Username, Kingdom Name, Email in use (I've edited it a tiny bit for my use). However it doesn't show the list. oh shoot, nevermind, the other two are still using rows. Thank you VERY much :)

Comment: I’m just concatenating it into a string, if it’s only showing one then either you’re still using else statements or your test values aren’t what you think. Post your updated code.

Comment: okay, so I was able to finish my registration process with error handling thanks to you! So thank you very very very much! (now the fun part of doing a passport login :O)

Comment: Don't forget to mark answered if this solved it for you

Answer (score 2):

You are processing the results even if the err condition is set or if no rows have been returned. Do not try to access rows if err is set.

You also need to iterate over rows as your SELECT could return multiple rows.  Do not access rows.username directly.  Use foreach instead to check for all the results.

If you want the rows where any of the columns match, then use 'OR'.

```
WHERE username = ? OR kigname = ? OR email = ?
```

You should not need to pass the binding values as an array of arrays, just a single array.

```
[username, kingname, email]
```

Comment: Hmmm, this will work, but what about the flash messages? How would I make that know which to take? For username, or the other two, or all three? I imagine I can do that within the flash function itself, right?

Comment: A simple solution would be to check the result against each parameter.

Comment: I know that much, but in this situation I'm not sure how. How do I check against the username parameter? Or any of them really.

Comment: if (row.username == username) ... show username popup
else if (row.kingname == kingname) ... show kingname popup
else if (row.email == email) ... show email popup

something like that

Comment: Hmm, I did this and my webpage just rests in a loading state. I can't copy paste my code in the comments unfortunately. -- updated OP so you can see.

Comment: Also, I would like for it ignore lower/uppercase? I know I can probably just force the function to look at them as lowercase using the built in function, but I was wondering if it did this by default

Comment: Are there errors or logs?  Also, use foreach to<loop through all the rows.

Comment: @William String comparison depends on your collation settings. Some are case insensitive. It's something you'll have to test.

Comment: There weren't any error logs, however I updated my OP again with a for loop, and I do get an error on startup here:       for (var = 0; i < rowLength; i++){
               ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token =

Comment: Looks like a variable name is missing.  Also, you're still using rows directly.